# ns-toggle-fullscreen on a mac

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs

How does the the ns-toggle fullscreen work on a mac keyboard ie what are the keys corresponding to each of ns, toggle and FS?

I'm sorry that this might be very basic but every post on google that talks about this assumes that I know what keys its referring to. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've spent more than an hour of searching for this.

Comment: You can press `C-h w <function_name>` inside Emacs to get the current keybinding associated with a particular function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F11, but be aware the nightly builds are crashing when I try it -- the stable releases are probably okay.

Comment: Thanks -- FS is F11 but what is "ns"?

Comment: If you press M-x ns RET  you will get a list of the ns options that are installed.  This is created during the build process when making the application -- the src folder that is used when building the application contains:  nsfns.m; nsfont.m; nsgui.h; nsimage.m; nsmenu.m; nsselect.m; nsterm.h; nsterm.m.  The term directory contains ns.win.el or elc, which also relates to ns functions.  In short, someone decided ns is a good prefix . . . perhaps someone else has a history of the development of ns, but that is somewhat beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Since the issue is resolved, perhaps you could please check the check-mark button to give me a brownie point to my reputation score.

Comment: Sorry for that -- I am unable to upvote because I need at least 15 reputation points for it first. Coming back to the question, I am still confused about what keys need to be pressed to perform this "ns-toggle-FS" function? I suppose its a sequence of three buttons... of which the second one is the shift button and the third one is F11. But what is the first one? This is what I meant when I asked the question. Thanks.

Comment: Only F11 is the default -- nothing else -- no shift -- no second button -- no third button -- just F11.  You can add your own keyboard shortcuts by doing a search in this forum or Google for: `global set key emacs`

Comment: Underneath the area for up/down votes to the left of this answer, there is a mouse-over area to check-mark and accept the answer to your question.  If you click it, the white check-mark will turn green and I'll get my bonus point :)

Comment: Check your OSX System Preferences to make sure the keyboard settings have a check-mark for:  Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys.  When this option is selected, press the Fn key to use the special features printed on each key.

Comment: ns = NextStep. Since this code set for OSX is based on Cocoa (the OSX toolkit), which in turn is based on the original NextStep, the ns prefix carries forward.  The Cocoa APIs still use ns- as the API prefix.

Comment: I learned something new tonight -- thank you very much -- greatly appreciated!